# how to install custom strapi in typescript

Tags: strapi

im just run to custom strapi, but Error: Server does not support secure connection, i dont no whats wrong in there, can anyone help me to fix my code
PS C:\belajar\layanan\backend\api> npm run develop

> api@0.1.0 develop
> strapi develop

Starting the compilation for TypeScript files in C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API
Building your admin UI with development configuration...
Admin UI built successfully
Error: Server does not support secure connection
at Handshake.HandshakeInitializationPacket (C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:63:17)
at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
at Parser._parsePacket (C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
at Parser.write (C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
at Protocol.write (C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket. (C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
at Socket. (C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
at Protocol.handshake (C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
at Connection.connect (C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
at C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql\index.js:66:18
at new Promise ()
at Client_MySQL.acquireRawConnection (C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql\index.js:61:12)
at create (C:\belajar\layanan\backend\API\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:254:39) {
code: 'HANDSHAKE_NO_SSL_SUPPORT',
fatal: true
}

pls help me i dont no

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.